presto sql to generate dynamic dictionary column after group by
Have data like this:
id     timestamp          collection
1111    1721681210135     music
2222    1721681210140     weather
1111    1721681210100     art
1111    1721681210000     music
.........

need to aggregate to a dictionary like column after group by
expected output is like:
id      collection_counts
1111    "music":2,"art":1
2222    "weather":1
............

Which function could be proper for this purpose? Presto doc is so easy to find examples.

You can use the histogram function:

Returns a map containing the count of the number of times each input value occurs.

select id, histogram(collection) as collection_counts
from data
group by id;

Output:



id
collection_counts




1111
{art=1, music=2}


2222
{weather=1}




Presto doc is not so easy to use, but tried to use the following to get this done.
WITH data(id, time_infor, collection) AS (
    VALUES
        (1111, 1721681210135, 'music'),
        (2222 ,   1721681210140,     'weather'),
        (1111,    1721681210100,     'art'),
        (1111,    1721681210000,     'music')
)

select id, map_agg(collection, counts) as collection_counts from (
select id, collection,count(*) as counts 
from data
group by id,collection
)
group by id

The output is:
id    collection_counts
    
1111  {art=1, music=2}  
2222  {weather=1}

